# LC-3 print the result with two number after adding

Tags: assembly, ascii, lc3

I wrote this small program that tries to add a number from 0 to 9 and print the result.

It has a bug: if the result is more than 9 it shows some crazy character. I'm not sure the right way to fix this.

```
.orig x3000
ld r6, m48

lea r0, id
puts

lea r0, numberone
puts

getc
out
add r1, r0, 0


lea r0, numbertwo
puts

getc
out
add r2, r0, 0

lea r0, line

puts 
add r0, r1, 0
out

lea r0, display
puts
add r0, r2, 0
out

lea r0, equalization
puts

lea r0, result
puts
add r0, r2, r1
add r0, r0, r6
out

halt

id      .stringz "------"
numberone   .stringz "\nPlease enter first number"
numbertwo   .stringz "\nPlease enter second number"
display     .stringz " + "
line        .stringz "\n----: "
equalization    .stringz "\nanswer: "
m48 .fill -48
result      .stringz "  "

.end
```

Comment: I would recommend you check to see if the solution is greater than 9, if it is then subtracting 10. That value is then your right most digit. From there you can print a "1" and the new digit produced from subtracting 10. Example: 9 + 5 = 14.    14 - 10 = 4.       print a 1, then print the 4.

Comment: The reason why you're getting a random character when you do "9 + 2" is because the ASCII version of that is 57 + 50 = 107, then you are subtracting 48 from 107 with equals 59. In ASCII 59 is the ";" character

Comment: Thanks guys.

I tried to make it but I field. Can you please change the code for me? Thanks.

Comment: Assuming this is a homework assignment, and we probably shouldn't code it for you. If you want to post your new code, and ask us specific questions, we'd be happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

**The problem is that you are not accounting for answers with more than one digit.** I commented the fixed version of your code (below) for you and others to understand as I step through a few examples; I recommend that you take a look at an [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

For 2 + 3 (working as given), you

1. get the ASCII code for `'2'` and `'3'` as inputs, setting `R0` to `50` and `R1` to `51`
2. `ADD R0, R0, R1`, which puts `101` in `R0`
3. subtract `48` from `R0` to get `53`, which is the ASCII code for `'5'` (the answer)

For 5 + 6 (not working as given), the provided code does this...

1. get the ASCII code for `'5'` and `'6'` as inputs, setting `R0` to `53` and `R1` to `54`
2. `ADD R0, R0, R1`, which puts `107` in `R0`
3. subtract `48` from `R0` to get `59`, which is the ASCII code for `';'` (not the answer)

For x + y (FIX), ...

1. get the ASCII code for `x` and `y` as inputs, setting `R0` to `x + 48` and `R1` to `y + 48` (addition automatically done by `GETC`)
2. `ADD R0, R0, R1`, which puts `x + y + 96` in `R0`
3. subtract `48` from `R0` to get `x + y + 48`
4. subtract `57` the ASCII code for `'9'` from `R0` and put the result in `R1`
5. we know that if `R0 - 57 <= 0` then `R0` is between (inclusive) `'0'` and `'9'` (assuming valid input), so `BRnz DONE` where `DONE OUT` (and then `HALT`)
6. at this point, the program is only running if `R0` is holding a value greater than `'9'`, meaning that our answer is not one digit
7. because the question specifies that the addends are "from 0 to 9," we know that any valid answer that is not one digit must be from 10 to 18, so we store the digits in `R2` and `LD R0, p49` where `p49 .fill 49` and `OUT`, which prints `'1'`
8. the only thing left to do is put the ASCII code for the other digit in `R2` so that it is printed when we reach `DONE OUT`, so we `ADD R0, R2, -10`

**Fixed version:**

```
.orig x3000
LD R6, m48          ; ASCII char. val. - m48 = dec. int. val.
LEA R0, id          ; get a horizontal line
PUTS                ; print
LEA R0, numberone   ; get prompt for first number
PUTS                ; print
GETC                ; get first number (ASCII char. val.),
                    ; we will call this A1
OUT                 ; print
ADD R1, R0, 0       ; put A1 in R1
LEA R0, numbertwo   ; get prompt for second number
PUTS                ; print
GETC                ; get second number (ASCII char. val.),
                    ; we will call this A2
OUT                 ; print
ADD R2, R0, 0       ; put A2 in R2
LEA R0, line        ;
PUTS                ; doing some stuff here to get the output below...
ADD R0, R1, 0       ; ┌─────────────┐
OUT                 ; │-----        │
LEA R0, display     ; │A1 + A2      │
PUTS                ; │answer:      │
ADD R0, R2, 0       ; └─────────────┘
OUT                 ;
LEA R0, equalization
PUTS                ;
LEA R0, result      ; everything looks good so far,
PUTS                ; now all we need is the answer...
ADD R0, R2, R1      ; put the sum in R0
ADD R0, R0, R6      ; subtract 48 (to get the ASCII char. val.)
                    ; ERROR: there is no ASCII char. val. for n > 9,
                    ; FIX:
LD R5, m57          ; get '9' == 57 (but negative, for subtraction)
ADD R1, R0, R5      ; if ((answer - '9') <= 0),
BRnz DONE           ; then answer is a single digit, print
ADD R2, R0, 0       ; else store the digits in R2
LD R0, p49          ; get 1
OUT                 ; print
ADD R0, R2, -10     ; get the second digit
DONE OUT            ; print
HALT
id              .stringz "-----"
numberone       .stringz "\nPlease enter first number: "
numbertwo       .stringz "\nPlease enter second number: "
display         .stringz " + "
line            .stringz "\n-----: "
equalization    .stringz "\nanswer: "
m48 .fill -48
m57 .fill -57   ; -(the ASCII code for '9')
p49 .fill 49    ; the ASCII code for '1'
result          .stringz "  "
.end
```